Python Interpreter Selection in VSCodium
I have multiple Python interpreters installed, all of which are the same version (3.12.3). Additionally, two of these interpreters are located in the same directory. Which interpreter should I remove by deleting its folder?
Python 3.12.3 (.venv: venv) - Recommended: ./venv/bin/python
Python 3.12.3 64-bit - Global: /bin/python
Python 3.12.3 64-bit: /bin/python
Python 3.12.3 64-bit: /usr/bin/python3


Additional information:

VSCodium version: 1.91.1 (release: 24193)
Python version: 3.12.3
Operating system: Ubuntu 24.04


Could you specify what additional details you are looking for? What aspects of my question are unclear or need further clarification?

I am sending my comment as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment?
If you find my answer helpful, please upvote.
As a long-term vscode user I can say, this is an expected behavior. The program scans for possible paths to find a python binary.
/usr/bin/python3 this is where python is installed system-wide
/bin/python this is probably linking to /usr/bin/python3
./.venv/bin/python3 you need to learn python venv if you don't know what this means. It is simply a copy of your system-wide python interpreter. Virtual environments help you create an isolated environment for your project. If you are working on a project created by someone else you may need this venv. I could help better if there is more detail.

/bin/python being shown twice apparently is a bug of vscodium. Nothing to worry
